# XAMPP error with running MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have problem witch XAMPP. When I try to run MySQL, XAMPP shows this:

```
12:37:02  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:37:02  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing  dependencies, 
12:37:02  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:37:02  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:37:02  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:37:02  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:37:02  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I've changed ports to 3307 in
`C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`
 and in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` to `mysql.default_port=3307
mysqli.default_port=3307`.

I've also deleted `ib_logfile1` in `C:\xampp\mysql\data`
, but it still doesn't work.
Error logs:

```
2017-08-17 12:27:00 2050 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB. `

2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-08-17 12:27:00 8272 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try restarting your system.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is telling you exactly why it cannot start:

> [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101

Hence I suggest the first thing you do is to check that c:\xampp\mysql\data exists and is writeable by the DBMS user.

Answer (score 0):

First stop the service on the xampp control panel,
then click on the red cross on the left to install the service on your computer,
then the icon will become a green tick,
then start the service as administrator.

It should be working alright.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the XAMPP control panel and stop the actions.
2. Open services and go to MySql80.
3. Stop the service.
4. Start the service.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).